# Using a C++ dll from C# - not getting expected results

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

```
int JPEG_CODEC_API jpeg_decompress(unsigned char *jpeg_buf, 
                               unsigned long jpeg_len, 
                               EImage_S** * img);


* @param jpeg_buf [in]     JPEG buffer
* @param jpeg_len [in]     JPEG buffer length
* @param img [out]     decompress data

    internal struct EImage_S
    {
        public byte[] imagedata;
        public int image_size;
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public int widthStep;
    };
```

I declared it like this;

```
[DllImport("JpegLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] internal static extern int jpeg_decompress(byte[] jpeg_buf, uint jpeg_len, ref IntPtr Img);

EImage_S obj = (EImage_S)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(EImage_S));
```

When i call PtrToStructure, it give an error as "Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem".

I'm not sure what is wrong!

Comment: Show more code... calling it for example.

Comment: There are many, using jpeglib from unmanaged C is hard to do, it doesn't get any easier when you pinvoke it.  Memory management in particular is a tricky problem.  Which is why everybody uses the .NET Bitmap or JpegBitmapDecoder class instead.  If using jpeglib is a hard requirement for some reason then avoid re-inventing the wheel, google ".net jpeglib wrapper" to take advantage of others having solved this already.

Answer (score 3):

You can, and should, remove the `unsafe` keyword. It is not necessary here.

The first parameter is declared incorrectly in the p/invoke. It should be:

```
byte[] jpeg_buf
```

Using `ref` for a managed type is never correct in p/invoke. There's no way a native function will be able to create a .net managed type.

The final parameter is probably incorrect too. It is, I believe, impossible to say for sure how that parameter should be declared and managed, with the information that you present. You need to show us what `Image_S` is, and explain clearly the semantics of that parameter. Who allocates the memory? How much is allocated? Is it an array? If not, what is it. Example C++ code that calls the function would help.

---

Your update removes the code on which the above answer was based. The struct that you now show cannot be marshalled because of the array. That's what the runtime error is about.

I cannot tell you how to marshal that struct because you've not described the native side of the interface.

To solve this problem you do need to understand the native side. You cannot expect to make any progress without doing so. As I said above, an example of native code calling the function would probably make it all clear.

Finally, why are you using this library rather than the built in managed classes?

Comment: Image_S is a custom struct. i edited my question above. C++ function allocates the memory.

Comment: That struct cannot be marshalled. The array ensures that. It seems likely that the third param needs initialization by caller. Only you can know how to do that. You need to recognise that a function prototype does not give enough information to know how to call the function. Without more detail we cannot help any more than we have done so far.  Also your edit is badly formatted. Please can you format it.

Comment: Are you still needing help with this question?

Comment: I haven't solve yet but firstly i need to learn the easy subject. After that i will try to solve it. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: OK, but this site is about answering the questions you ask rather than solving your problems. It's on you to solve your problems. We can just answer the questions you ask.

Comment: I am sorry if i am misunderstood. I know this site is about answering site and i dont use like a tutorial. Just i could realize that i need to learn other title firstly. After that i will try and solve this quesiton.